# Как сделать камеру за игроком Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, камера

Я захотел сделать игру, где мой персонаж будет передвигаться по карте(больше окна), а камера будет за ним следовать. Все было хорошо до момента реализации камеры. Я посмотрел множество роликов и сайтов, но понял, что что-то там не то, либо я не понимаю. Скажите пожалуйста что можно поделать

```
import pygame
from pygame import key
import os
import sys


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_caption('Adventures')
    size = width,height = 1000,1000
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    running = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    FPS = 60
    map = []

    with open('samples\map.map',encoding='utf-8') as f:
        count = 0
        for i in f:
            map.append([])
            for z in range(1,len(i)):
                map[count].append(i[z-1:z])
            count += 1
        map[-1].append('#')


    #загрузка изображения игрока
    def load_image(name, color_key=None):
        fullname = os.path.join('samples', name)
        try:
            image = pygame.image.load(fullname).convert()
        except pygame.error as message:
            print('Cannot load image:', name)
            raise SystemExit(message)
        if color_key is not None:
            if color_key == -1:
                color_key = image.get_at((0, 0))
                image.set_colorkey(color_key)
                return image
            else:
                image = image.convert_alpha()
                return image

    l = 0
    t = 0

    for i in range(len(map)):
        for z in range(len(map[i])):
            if map[i][z] == 'P':
                l = z
                t = i



    class Camera():
        def __init__(self):
            self.camera_func = camera_func
            self.state = Rect(0,0,width,height)




    class Player():
        image = load_image('player.png',-1)

        def __init__(self,screen):
            self.screen = screen
            self.ps = pygame.sprite.Group()

            self.sprite = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
            self.sprite.image = Player.image
            self.sprite.rect = self.sprite.image.get_rect()
            self.ps.add(self.sprite)

        def spawning(self,l,t):
            self.sprite.rect.x = l * 90
            self.sprite.rect.y = t * 90
            self.ps.draw(self.screen)


    class Earth():
        image = load_image('grass.png',0)
        
        def __init__(self,screen):
            self.screen = screen
            self.ps = pygame.sprite.Group()

            self.sprite = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
            self.sprite.image = Earth.image
            self.sprite.rect = self.sprite.image.get_rect()
            self.ps.add(self.sprite)

        def spawning(self):
            for i in range(len(map)):
                for z in range(len(map[i])):
                    if map[i][z] == '.' or map[i][z] == 'P':
                        self.sprite.rect.x = z * 90
                        self.sprite.rect.y = i * 90
                        self.ps.draw(self.screen)
    
    class Box():
        image = load_image('box.png',0)
        
        def __init__(self,screen):
            self.screen = screen
            self.ps = pygame.sprite.Group()

            self.sprite = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
            self.sprite.image = Box.image
            self.sprite.rect = self.sprite.image.get_rect()
            self.ps.add(self.sprite)

        def spawning(self):
            for i in range(len(map)):
                for z in range(len(map[i])):
                    if map[i][z] == '#':
                        self.sprite.rect.x = z * 90
                        self.sprite.rect.y = i * 90
                        self.ps.draw(self.screen)


    pl = Player(screen)
    ear = Earth(screen)
    box = Box(screen)


    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                    print(map)
                    
        
        keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
        
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            if map[t-1][l] != '#':
                map[t][l] = '.'
                map[t-1][l] = 'P'
                t -= 1
        elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
            if map[t+1][l] != '#':
                map[t][l] = '.'
                map[t+1][l] = 'P'
                t += 1
        elif keys[pygame.K_a]:
            if map[t][l-1] != '#':
                map[t][l] = '.'
                map[t][l-1] = 'P'
                l -= 1
        elif keys[pygame.K_d]:
            if map[t][l+1] != '#':
                map[t][l] = '.'
                map[t][l+1] = 'P'
                l += 1

        ear.spawning()
        pl.spawning(l,t)
        box.spawning()



        clock.tick(FPS)
        pygame.display.flip()
        screen.fill('black')

    pygame.quit()
```

Ниже карта

```
#######################
#.....................#
#.....................#
#.....................#
#......P..............#
#.....................#
#.....................#
#.....................#
#.....................#
#.....................#
#.....................#
#######################
```

Это коробка, то есть типо стена
[image: Это коробка, то есть типо стена]

Земля
[image: Земля]

Сам спрайт игрока
[image: Сам спрайт игрока]

Результат на данный момент
[image: Результат на данный момент]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно отрисовывать карту на объекте `pygame.Surface`, потом "блитить" эту карту на экран с координатами равными отрицательным координатам персонажа, и если карта у вас не изменяется, то можно ее просто один раз отрисовать на объекте `pygame.Surface` и потом просто каждый кадр "блитить"
ту карту с учетом координат игрока вместо этой строчки:
`screen.fill('black')`

Answer (score 0):

Если дело в том что игрок не по центру, то нужно рисовать спрайт игрока относительно спрайта фона, то есть учитывать смещение, либо изменив спрайт игрока сделав его равным спрайту фона, что на мой взгляд лучше.

Если относительно сдвига карты, то... есть несколько вариантов: самый простой и самый убогий сдвиг карты относительно игрока, то есть спрайт игрока неподвижен, меняется карта. Более продвинутый вариант, карта подгружается, когда игрок подошёл к экрану ближе чем Х чегото. То есть делается задержка управления и анимация перемещения карты (так реализовано в pathos и мне нрав)

Comment: тут четко указано что надо чтобы камера следовала за игроком, чтобы не было как в `The Binding Of Isaac`, а вы советуете как раз сделать как в `TBOI`, поэтому минус.

Comment: Я как бы оба варианта описал,- и то что игрок не подвижен, перерисовывается лишь карта и столь ненавидимый вами..